# onClick function won't fire for mapped component

Tags: javascript, reactjs, onclick

Here is the relevant code:

```
const Members = () => {
  // array of each video in selected grade
  const videosMap = (videos) => {
    return videos.map((video) => (
      <VideoCard
        key={video.id}
        thumbnail={video.thumbnail}
        title={video.title}
        description={video.description}
        onClick={() => {
          handleVideoClick();
        }}
      />
    ));
  };

  // updates state of shown videos & page heading
  const handleGradeButtonClick = (videos, heading) => {
    setShowVideos(videosMap(videos));
    setVideosHeading(heading);
  };

  const handleVideoClick = () => {
    console.log("test");
  };

  // controls state of which grade's videos to show
  const [showVideos, setShowVideos] = useState(videosMap(kinder_videos));
  // controls states heading to display depending on selected grade
  const [videosHeading, setVideosHeading] = useState("Kindergarten");

  const [showVideoDetails, setShowVideoDetails] = useState(null);
```

The handleVideoClick is the function that is not working when I click on one of the mapped VideoCard components.

Here is the full code if you want to see that:
https://github.com/dblinkhorn/steam-lab/blob/main/src/components/pages/Members.js

When I look in React DevTools at one of the VideoCard components, it shows the following:

`onClick: *f* onClick() {}`

If I don't wrap it in an arrow function it does execute, but on component load instead of on click. I have a feeling it has something to do with my use of .map to render this component, but haven't been able to figure it out.

Thanks for any help!

Answer (score 0, accepted):

There's no problem with your mapping method, you just need to pass the onClick method as a prop to your VideoCard component :

On your VideoCard component do this :

```
const VideoCard = (props) => {
  const { thumbnail, description, title, onClick } = props;

  return (
    <div className="video-card__container" onClick={onClick}>
      <div className="video-card__thumbnail">
        <img src={thumbnail} />
      </div>
      <div className="video-card__description">
        <div className="video-card__title">
          <h3>{title}</h3>
        </div>
        <div className="video-card__text">{description}</div>
      </div>
    </div>
  );
};

export default VideoCard;
```